# type casting in C doesnt change 97 to 'a'

Tags: c, casting, char, printf, conversion-specifier

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", (int)('a'));
    printf("%d\n", (char)(97));
}
```

Why does the program above give the output

```
97
97
```

instead of

```
97
a
```

Comment: you're printing in %d, just print %c. You don't even need to cast for that.

Comment: `%d` tells printf to print the decimal representation of the corresponding parameter and `97` is strictly equivalent to `'a'`. Try `printf("%c\n", 97)` and `printf("%c\n", 'a')`. The `()` casts are useless, the have no effect here.

Comment: If you want to see the output `a` you need format `%c` instead of `%d`. `%d` expects a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", (int)('a'));
    printf("%c\n", (char)(97));
}
```

`char` is an integral type (same as `int`, `long`, `long long` etc etc), only ranges are different.

`%d` printf integer, character constant `'a'` has type `int` and value `97` in `ASCII`.

You do not need casts in your example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", 'a');
    printf("%c\n", 97);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`97`, `0x61` and `'a'` are just different ways of producing the same `int` value (at least on an ASCII-based machine).

And `char` is just another integer type, so casting the value to a `char` isn't going to help.

To print that value as `a`, use `%c`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("%d\n", 97);   // 97
   printf("%d\n", 'a');  // 97

   printf("%c\n", 97);   // a
   printf("%c\n", 'a');  // a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second call you are trying to output a character as an integer using the conversion specifier `%d`.

```
printf("%d\n", (char)(97));
```

Instead you could just write using the conversion specifier `%c`

```
printf("%c\n", 97);
```

In this case the casting is not required.

Pay attention to that even if you will write

```
printf("%c\n", (char)(97));
```

or

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%c\n", c);
```

nevertheless the second argument expression will be promoted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions.

Also in C integer character constants like `'a'` have the type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need write %c, not %d in the last line.

```
printf("%d\n", (char)(97));
```

to

```
printf("%c\n", 97);
```

Comment: The casts are useless, `(char)(97)` ->`97`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is printing a character, but in your second printf call you specify format `%d` instead of `%c`, then printf output your `(char)(97)` as an integer.